# The import net.minecraft.util.text cannot be resolved

Tags: java, minecraft

When I started modding I tried to

```
import net.minecraft.util.text.TextComponentString;
import net.minecraft.util.text.TextFormatting;
```

but **eclipse** told me that

```
The import net.minecraft.util.text cannot be resolved
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you have the applicable jars in your build path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

```
net.minecraft.util.text.TextComponentString;
```

and

```
net.minecraft.util.text.TextFormatting;
```

doesn't exist in minecraft's source code and it's actually writted by nullbear.
[net.minecraft.util.text.TextComponentString;](https://github.com/nullbear/minecraft/blob/master/net/minecraft/util/text/TextComponentString.java)

[net.minecraft.util.text.TextFormatting;](https://github.com/nullbear/minecraft/blob/master/net/minecraft/util/text/TextFormatting.java)